# Installing Ubuntu Server on Barracuda Backup Server 490

Tags: server, backup

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. But I have an old Barracuda Backup Server 490 that I want to re purpose. But Barraduca's rates are pretty steep when it comes to using their hardware. I was wondering if there was any way I could install Ubuntu Server on the server and use it again for my own use? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We aren't specialists on Barracuda Networks legal policy AFAIK, since your question may have a legal component you should begin by reading [this](https://www.barracuda.com/legal) and perhaps contact the company directly [here](https://www.barracuda.com/company/contact)

As far as installation procedures are concerned that topic has been covered extensively in [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server) document.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Barracuda and can honestly say this will not be easy. The only way to do so would have to be hard-hacking it. You would need to open the sucker up and locate the GPIO ports. There may be some kinds of terminal interface, JTAG, SPI, UART, I have no idea... MAYBE you could do this. You could try SSH'ing into it but you would need to spoof Barracuda's IP since it's the only address allowed to SSH into the unit. I know the IP now is 64.235.147.75 but if it is old it may be different. I would have to say these proprietary systems are made to need support from a Barracuda Technical Support Representative.